# Writing a Simple Video Viewer/Frame Grabber in C# for a USB Camera

Tags: c#, .net, video, video-capture, image-capture

I'm a complete beginner in C#, but I'm trying to write a very simple application in C# (VS2013) to simply view video stream or capture frames from a Sony FCB-EV7500 camera. The camera connects to a small USB3 board using CN401, and the board connects to the laptop via USB3. I can view video in VLC for example, but i'd like to write code in a C# application to get video/grab frames.

Google searching this brought me to DirectShow which apparently is only a C++ library. There used to be a DirectShow.NET wrapper available here: http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/about.html but it seems they haven't updated the project since 2010 and a lot of functions/interfaces at that time remained untested.

Are there any commonly used libraries for accomplishing this in C#? Perhaps something included in the .NET framework? Thanks for any advice or direction.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to be marshaling full frame rate video into a C# application.
You should probably take a look at the .net bindings for gstreamer,  I have personally only used the C and python bindings so YMMV.  If that doesn't work you will need to:

1. Use direct show, gstreamer, or ffmpeg to deal with media.
2. Write a native wrapper around your media handling code.
3. Write C# code to interop with your wrapper.

depending on if you are using winforms or wpf you will either use a `NativeWindow` or `D3DImageSource` as your render target.

Comment: If I have a .dll for DirectShow (implemented in C++), would I be able to just add that .dll to my resources in a C# project in visual studio?

Comment: Direct Show filters are not normal DLLs.  They are COM objects designed to work with a bunch of other COM objects that are part of the DS framework, so you might be able to add it to your project but it won't do what you expect.